# Cannot trigger Jenkins MultiBranch Pipeline jobs from a git mirror

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-mirror

My Jenkins server is not receiving notification that the git server has changed content, and therefore not triggering the Multibranch Pipeline jobs.

The configuration is as follows:

1. The main git server is internet facing and running gitolite.
2. The Jenkins server is behind a firewall. The main git server does not have access to the Jenkins server, so git hooks will not work from this git server.
3. A git mirror exists on the Jenkins machine which acts as a read-only cache for Jenkins to reduce external bandwidth usage. I will just call this the cache in the rest of the description. The cache is being published internally using git-daemon.
4. The cache is updated by a Jenkins job that runs every 5 minutes to update it from the main git server using

```
    git remote update
    git fetch
```

5. Existing freestyle projects simply poll the git cache to trigger themselves when changes appear in the cache. **This works correctly**.

The problem arises from recently created MultiBranch pipeline jobs. I cannot determine a way to trigger these jobs when the cache changes. I would prefer to use git hooks from the git cache and have tried setting up `post-receive` hooks containing:

```
curl <jenkins server url>/git/notifyCommit?url=<cache url>/<project name>
```

Manually running this `post-receive` does trigger the correct Jenkins jobs including the MultiBranch Pipeline ones, so the command within `post-receive` is correct. But when the cache updates, that hook is not run. Is there any other hook I can use to trigger the build? If no hooks are appropriate, is there any way I set up a MultiBranch Pipeline job to poll the cache for changes?

Comment: I've been encountering the same issue under my new install of Jenkins 2.227, and I have a possible workaround:

On non-multibranch projects I've had to enable the "Poll SCM" function, with an empty schedule, to get /git/notifyCommit to trigger a new build.

Same goes on multibranch projects, however since mine are defined with a `Jenkinsfile`, I had to add `triggers { pollSCM('') }` to my pipeline declaration. It seems hacky and weird, so I'm interested in a proper answer as well